# How can I conveniently wrap a caller-sensitive API?

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

Certain Java APIs are caller-sensitive.  One (woefully underdocumented IMO) example is `System.load()`, which loads some JNI code into the caller's `ClassLoader` only.

I have a wrapper that looks roughly like `JniUtils.loadLibrary("nameoflibrary")`.  It finds the appropriate library for the current architecture, extracts it out of the JAR, and passes it to `System.load()`.  But I just ran into a case where the caller of `JniUtils.loadLibrary` wasn't in the same `ClassLoader` as `Jni` itself.  That caused the library to get loaded into the wrong `ClassLoader`, resulting in `UnsatisfiedLinkError` once the native methods got called.

Without relying on JVM internals like `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass()`, is there a way to work around this issue?  My current idea is to change the wrapper like this:

```
public class JniUtils {
    public static void loadLibrary(String libraryName, MethodHandles.Lookup lookup);
}
```

which can be called like this:

```
public class NeedsJni {
    static {
        JniUtils.loadLibrary("nameoflibrary", MethodHandles.lookup());
    }
}
```

Using the `Lookup` to resolve and call the `System.load()` method [should preserve `NeedsJni` as the caller](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#callsens).

Is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your problem, this may or may not be applicable.

Under a context without reflection, it's hard for standard java code to replicate caller-sensitivity, even more so to "emulate" it to a caller-sensitive function. Even if it were done the code, in my opinion, would be incredibly obscure or would deal with deep dark language features that I would consider unnecessary.

The fundamental problem you have here is that `System.load()` is caller sensitive and you're trying to build your own "enhanced" `System.load()` by doing a bunch of other tasks prior to calling `System.load()` yourself. Why not leave `System.load()` exactly where it was when you started?

Rather than trying to replace the functionality of `System.load()`, complement it with your `JniUtils` class. Write a `JniUtils.fetchLibrary()` which returns a string in which the original caller can load from. Even better, return a custom object `Library` (or other names to that equivalent) containing a method that allows the retrieval of the string that should be passed to `System.load()`. From this, the call to `load()` can come from the point of need whilst your caller-insensitive code can do all the initialization separately.

Something to this example would be good:

```
public class JniUtils {
    private static final HashMap<String, JniLibrary> cachedLibs = new HashMap<>();

    public static JniLibrary fetchLibrary(String libname){
        // Check cache for library
        if(cachedLibs.containsKey(libname)){
            return cachedLibs.get(libname);
        }else{
            JniLibrary lib = preloadLibrary(libname);

            if(lib != null){
                cachedLibs.put(libname, lib);
            }

            return lib;
        }
    }

   /**
    * Internal logic to prepare and generate a library instance
    *
    * @return JNI library on success, null on failure.
    */
    private static JniLibrary preloadLibrary(String libname){
        // Find lib
        // Extract
        // Get path
        // Construct JniLibrary instance
        // Return library as appropriate
    }

   /**
    * Class representing a loadable JniLibrary
    */
    public class JniLibrary{
        public String getLibraryPath();

        // Other potentially useful methods
    }
}

public class NeedsJni {
    static {
        JniLibrary lib = JniUtils.fetchLibrary("nameoflibrary");

        if(lib != null){
            System.load(lib.getLibraryPath()); // Caller-sensitivity respected
        }else{
            // Well.... this is awkward.
        }
    }
}
```

not only does that solve the caller-sensitivity issue, the additional caching prevents additional extraction/architecture lookup and eventual failure (since the file you extract to would probably have been in use), allowing multiple calls to `System.load()` from different classes under different classloaders as appropriate.

The countercase to this approach is that if there is important code that has to be executed right after `System.load()` in your custom `loadLibrary()` method (suddenly, you wished java would have some sort of "OnLibraryLoad" event). In that case, perhaps add a method to run the post-load code within your main `JniUtils` class or the returned Library class (it's more ugly I know, but with clear documentation, it can't be that bad).

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining an abstract class which has to be provided if the classpath is going to be incompatible. This provides "caller sensitivity" as the caller has to provide the implementation, thus providing the necessary context.

```
public class JniUtils {
    public static void loadLibrary(String libraryName, Delegate delegate) {
        //use delegate's provided classloader to find the native library from within the jar and extract 
        //ask the delegate to load the extracted library
    }

    public static abstract class Delegate {

        /**
         * @return The specific ClassLoader instance to use to find the native resource. If returning null, the ClassLoader of JniUtils will be used.
         */
        public ClassLoader getLibraryClassLoader() {
            return getClass().getClassLoader();
        }

        /**
         * <p>
         * The callback method which will be called once the native library's name has been
         * resolved. This MUST be implemented by the subclass, so that it resolves as the "caller"
         * class for {@link System#loadLibrary(String)}.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @param libraryName The name of the library to load.
         */
        public abstract void loadLibrary(String libraryName);
    }
}
```